# MYSQL weighted average by group

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have a mysql table with the following structure

```
| Field          | Type         | 
+----------------+--------------+
| Data           | timestamp    | 
| ticker         | varchar(250) |                                        
| sentiment      | double       |                                            
| numberofTweets | int(11)      |
```

And there are 70 different tickers, i need to calculate the weighted average for each one.

I am doing the following:

```
select ticker, round(sum(sentiment)/sum(numberofTweets),2) as wAverage
from sentiment
WHERE ticker = 'GBP/USD'
order by data desc
limit 288;
```

Are there a way to do for all tickers in a single query?

Tks in advance!

EDIT 1:

I need to use 288 records for each ticker to make the calculations, so using GROUP BY clausule will not work!

Comment: Avarage overall or each ticker?

Comment: For each ticker

Comment: Use `GROUP BY ticker` instead of `WHERE ...`

Comment: Paul using 'group by limit 288' it will select 288 last records for each ticker and then make calculations?

Comment: No :-)  - Do you want the average of the latest 288 rows each ticker?

Comment: Yes the average of 288 of each ticker! :D

Comment: This is ways more complex. Do you have a table containing unique tickers?

Comment: No, but i can create one!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the info you wrote in comments.

Comment: Do you have rows for each "timestamp"?  If so, we can go back 288 time units for filtering.  If not, the code gets messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your issue I use the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `group_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `val` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The test data contains 100 groups with an average of 1000 items each (100K rows overall).

```
set @num_rows = 100000;
set @per_group = 1000;
set @num_groups = @num_rows div @per_group;

insert into items (id, group_id, val)
    select seq as id
        , floor(rand(1)*@num_groups) + 1 as group_id
        , rand(2) as val
    from seq_1_to_1000000
    where seq <= @num_rows
;
```

**The task:** Get a sum of `val` for the latest 288 rows per `group_id`.

Without the requirement of 288 rows per group it would simply be

```
select group_id, sum(val)
from items
group by group_id
```

But you first you need to limit your data set to 288 rows per group. Search for "mysql top n per group" and you will find a lot of related questions on SO.

Most of the answers will use session variables:

```
select group_id, sum(val)
from (
    select i.group_id, i.val,
        case when i.group_id = @group 
            then @rn:=@rn+1
            else @rn:=1
        end rn,
        @group := i.group_id 
    from items i
    cross join (select @rn := null, @group := null) init_vars
    order by i.group_id, i.id desc
) t
where rn <= 288
group by group_id
order by group_id
```

Query time: 62 - 78 ms (my client doesn't show exact numbers). However - using this solution you rely on execution order of the engine, which might change in future versions.

Some other answers use a selfjoin:

```
select group_id, sum(val)
from (
    select i.group_id, i.val
    from items i
    join items i1
        on  i1.group_id = i.group_id
        and i1.id >= i.id
    group by i.id
    having count(*) <= 288
) t
group by group_id
order by group_id
```

But the performance is only acceptable with small groups (average group size <= 10). Query time: 17 sec.

There is also a "trick" with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(...), ...)`, which might need `@@group_concat_max_len` to be adjusted for large groups.
But I prefer this one:

```
select i.group_id, sum(i.val)
from items i
where i.id >= coalesce((
    select i1.id
    from items i1
    where i1.group_id = i.group_id
    order by i1.id desc
    limit 1
    offset 287
), 0)
group by i.group_id
order by i.group_id
```

It first finds the 288th highest id per group in the correlated subquery and only uses rows with higher or equal ids. If a group has less than 288 rows, all row will be used (id >= 0).
Query time: 78 - 94 ms.

Adjusting it to your question, you will get:

```
select s.ticker, round(sum(sentiment)/sum(numberofTweets),2) as wAverage
from sentiment s
where s.data >= coalesce((
    select s1.data 
    from sentiment s1
    where s1.ticker = s.ticker
    order by s1.data desc
    limit 1
    offset 287
), from_unixtime(0))
group by s.ticker
order by s.ticker
```

Note that if you sort a result by a not unique column, the limted result set is not well defined. So it's possible that it will use 289 or more rows, if two timestams are equal. It's better to use an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Paul sorry for this long delay, tonight i will try what i learned with you! tks